# Show mobile view using single controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a website which is developed by MVC. It is not responsive design. So i have created separate view with same controller. Please help me how to show mobile view based on device in MVC.?

For example,

**Desktop View:**

Views/Home/Index.cshtml

Views/Home/About.cshtml

**Mobile View:**

Views/Home/Mobile/Index.cshtml

Views/Home/Mobile/About.cshtml

Comment: if you are early stage in UI development of your application, consider using bootstrap and @media query for designing responsive design. This is now becoming a standard for UI design compatible to all devices ranging from desktop to tablets and mobiles, and will also save you from the nightmare of maintaining two views for the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Already desktop view done earlier and it has not responsive design. So that i want to create separate mobile folder with same controller.